# Parallax scrolling with sections at not-fixed/100% height?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, parallax, screen-resolution

I've been using some javascript that has achieved what I wanted as far as parallax scrolling. Only now i've seen it on a 22" iMac and I know the fact that it's height in pixels is going to be a problem especially for the style of this website.

The HTML uses sections with the CSS being:

```
.pages {
min-height: 1050px;
height: 1050px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
position: relative;
}
```

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Cache the Window object
    $window = $(window);

   $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
     var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

      $(window).scroll(function() {

        // Scroll the background at var speed
        // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!                              
    var yPos = -( ($window.scrollTop() - $bgobj.offset().top) / $bgobj.data('speed'));

        // Put together our final background position
        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';


        $bgobj.css({ 
     backgroundPosition: coords,
     '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
     '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
     '-o-background-size': 'cover',
     'background-size': 'cover'

             });

}); // window scroll Ends

 });    

}); 

/* 
 * Create HTML5 elements for IE's sake
 */

document.createElement("article");
document.createElement("section");
```

So if anybody could help me out with both/either of these 2 questions:

1. How can I make a section's height 100% of the the user's screen ? Simply changing height and min-height to 100% doesn't do that - the sections "disappear".
2. Is it possible to change this script so that images are re-sized from the centre (of the height) of the image and not from the top left corner ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I built a parallax site using jquery and found these two variables popping up all over my code:

   ```
   var height = $(window).height();
   var depth = $(window).scrollTop();
   ```

   You can use these to determine the height of the end user's screen as well as how far they are    currently scrolled down the page. The first variable named height should do the trick. scrollTop() will give you the location in pixels of the top of their current screen to the top of the page as a whole.
2. No you cannot resize an image from it's center, but that shouldn't be a huge issue, it just takes a little more time and calculation

Comment: I didn't per se, write the parallax script (or any of the javascript) - where within that parallax javascript I quoted, would I even put '$(window).height();' ?

Comment: @user3323016 it would be right after the $window = $(window); call. You could then use the height and depth variables throughout your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. A little more Infos on your code wouldn't be bad.

   But you have to run something like that on the (document).ready
   event:

   ```
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   $('.pages').height.css('height', windowHeight)
   ```

   If it's responsive i suggest to also run this on the resize event.
2. Maybe i can Help you out if you create a jsfiddle or something. But i need to take a look at your Code.

Comment: ok if you could take a quick look at this I would appreciate it: jsfiddle.net/hB55a